# pandas pivot table for heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to generate a heatmap using seaborn, however I am having a small problem with the formatting of my data.

Currently, my data is in the form:

```
Name     Diag   Date
A        1       2006-12-01
A        1       1994-02-12
A        2       2001-07-23
B        2       1999-09-12
B        1       2016-10-12
C        3       2010-01-20
C        2       1998-08-20
```

I would like to create a heatmap (preferably in python) showing `Name` on one axis against `Diag` - if occured. I have tried to pivot the table using `pd.pivot`, however I was given the error

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

this came from:

piv = df.pivot_table(index='Name',columns='Diag')

Time is irrelevant, but I would like to show which `Names` have had which `Diag`, and which `Diag` combos cluster together. Do I need to create a new table for this or is it possible for that I have? In some cases the `Name` is not associated with all `Diag`

EDIT:
I have since tried:
piv = df.pivot_table(index='Name',columns='Diag', values='Time', aggfunc='mean')

However as Time is in datetime format, I end up with:
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: this question could greatly benefit from some code showing what you actually tried for your pivot syntax. Showing just the error leaves any of us reading it to have to guess quite a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate function, because for same index and column have multiple values and `pivot` need unique values only:

```
print (df)
  Name  Diag  Time
0    A     1    12 <-duplicates for same A, 1 different value
1    A     1    13 <-duplicates for same A, 1 different value
2    A     2    14
3    B     2    18
4    B     1     1
5    C     3     9
6    C     2     8

df = df.pivot_table(index='Name',columns='Diag', values='Time', aggfunc='mean')
print (df)
Diag     1     2    3
Name                 
A     12.5  14.0  NaN
B      1.0  18.0  NaN
C      NaN   8.0  9.0
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = df.groupby(['Name','Diag'])['Time'].mean().unstack()
print (df)
Diag     1     2    3
Name                 
A     12.5  14.0  NaN
B      1.0  18.0  NaN
C      NaN   8.0  9.0
```

EDIT:

You can also check all duplicates by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.duplicated(['Name','Diag'], keep=False), ['Name','Diag']]
print (df)
  Name  Diag
0    A     1
1    A     1
```

EDIT:

`mean` of datetimes is not easy - need convert dates to `nanoseconds`, get mean and last convert to datetimes. Also there is another problem - need replace `NaN` to some scalar, e.g. `0` what is converted to `0` datetime - `1970-01-01`.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['dates_in_ns'] = pd.Series(df.Date.values.astype(np.int64), index=df.index)
df = df.pivot_table(index='Name',
                    columns='Diag', 
                    values='dates_in_ns', 
                    aggfunc='mean', 
                    fill_value=0)
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
print (df)
Diag                   1          2          3
Name                                          
A    2000-07-07 12:00:00 2001-07-23 1970-01-01
B    2016-10-12 00:00:00 1999-09-12 1970-01-01
C    1970-01-01 00:00:00 1998-08-20 2010-01-20
```

Comment: Thanks! this is helpful. the problem now may be that time is actually in datatime format so is not numeric. perhaps I should just add a column on ones as a workaround?

Comment: I think it is same problem. But I have idea how check this values, give me a sec.

Comment: pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate is my current error. Unfortunatley i didnt put the correct data types in the example for Time its in the form '2016-12-12'

Comment: Ok, no problem. Main question is - do you need mean?

Comment: Or only first value?

Comment: I dont think i need mean, I would mainly like to show presence (exists or not) But as mean coujld apsp represent frequency i think it would be useful :)

Comment: Ok, can you update question to datetimes? Thank you.

Comment: The quesiton now is how to actually get the plot working :-P

Comment: Hmmm, it seems need only remove `df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)`, because need numeric.